# Data trend sorting

Tags: algorithm, sorting, trend

The issue is suppose i have unsorted data. I need to pass it to my algorithm in a manner following the signal trend. Below i have already shown you a sample case using a sine wave. Please do suggest an algorithm way i can sort my data in the trend shown in pic4. Do keep in mind this is a sample case I know for this sample case you can sort it along the z axis but i want a generalised method. As the actual data is far more fluctuating

this is the issue I am currently stuck at if this can be resolved I believe the wavelet algorithm can perform far much better as it would generate a better approximate signal.

The issue is mainly with data sorting. TO explain lets take an example of a signal shaped as a sine wave like Pic1.[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wut5Z.jpg)

In our case the data is randomly arranged hence when it is passed to the wavelet algorithm it appears something like Pic2.[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoBS5.jpg)
Bcz of this the wavelet algorithm tries to map onto this.Hence the approxiamte wave isnt accurate.

One approach that i have currently applied is to sort it along one axis eg in this case the x axis so the signal looks like Pic 3 .Here you can identify that the signal looks like a sine wave is better than the previous 2.but still can be improved. [Pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScnjM.jpg)

So i tried searching for some way that i can somehow sort the data in a way that it follows the signal and maybe not the axis. I would really appreciate if you can share your opinion or suggest any method.
On a note this is the sort of trend i am looking for [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WerEt.jpg).

I have already tried Knn but even it required data to be sorted. Have tried using np.polyfit but the fit dosent come even close. Have tried convex hull but dont see it happening there as well.

Answer (score 0):

All methods for doing this are heuristics, which quickly break down for more complicated examples.  But here is an approach that will work perfectly on your data, which can be adapted to handle things like figure 8s.

Throw all the data into a spatial index like a quad tree.  Pick a point at random.  Find its nearest neighbor. This gives us your first two points, remove them from the index.

And now proceed by doing nearest neighbor searches for each end, then of the two neighbors, take the closest one, add it to its end, and remove it from the index.

Proceed until you have all of the points.

That will work just fine on your data.  If this works, use it.  But it will do interestingly bad things on self-intersections like a figure 8.  If your real data has such complications, you can address it as follows.

Instead of looking for one nearest neighbor near the ends, look for a fixed but fairly small number `k`.  Like 3.  Instead of just looking for the nearest neighbor, have some fitness function based on how close it is to the path that you were previously on.  This will now go through intersections like a figure 8 and keep on in the same direction.

Of course this now gets messed up if your data has even a bit of noise in it.  To this you can add various kinds of averaging techniques to be determining an approximate path at the end.  And now as you're going along, mark points that the path passes near with, "this could have been inserted into the path".  Then when you finally add them, choose between inserting into the middle of the path or at the ends.

But if the first idea works, do that.  Don't go to complicated unless you have to.

Comment: Thanks for replying. In the first approach maybe due to my implementation. After selecting the starting point (PYTHON) it follows the signal to the right of the axis. Rather than going both ways I tried to hardcode to select the left most value as the starting point. But that again becomes only case dependent. Second using this i do get a rough trend but it dosent utilize all of the points of the data for eg for a data of 1000 it uses 50 before break. I cant attach code in comment as well as the pic since i am new to stack overflow. Otherwise i believe that could help you understand it better.